# How to write text on a mobile element without clearing it

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am working with appium to automate my native app. I need to write a test case to verify the search suggestions after typing each character.

While trying to do so, each and every time I use `element.sendKeys(string)` it erases the previous value in the text box. I need to type a string in a text box without clearing it. Any idea how it can be done?

Java - 1.8;
Appium java client - 5.0.2;
Appium server - 1.7

Comment: did u tried like typing few word of complete string, then wait for autosuggestion to come, then store them in a list and assert ?

Like this you have to do for multiple words by repeatedly sending different words

Comment: Yes that is a solution but inconsistent. As you know sendKeys types on a text box too fast, so the autosuggestion do not work sometimes. This can be handled by typing character by character with a delay of few milliseconds.

Comment: Firstly you can copy the existing string from the filed by using `.getText()` and keep it in a variable and then add the string with your current string > then put the full string in field by using `.sendKeys`

Answer (score 0):

Try to `tap` using `TouchAction` on the element before calling `sendKeys`.

This will not erase the text. This approach is working for me.

Also, I would suggest you to use latest Appium Java client (6.1.0) and server (1.9.1).

**Edit:**

You can use Java client 5.0.4 if you can't use latest version.

Sample code to tap using 5.0.4 is:

```
TouchAction touch = new TouchAction (driver);
touch.tap (e).perform ();
```

Also, if you want to have latest Appium Java client flavor without worrying about the major changes done in the new version, then you can try my open source framework [coteafs-appium](https://github.com/WasiqB/coteafs-appium) as I keep a stable methods exposed to the user and major Java client version changes are handled in the framework itself so it keep you worry free.

Comment: Cannot update appium server version as I am executing these test cases in amazon device farm. They provide appium server 1.7.2 and 1.7.1.

Also regarding appium java client updation the touch action class has changed a lot from 5.x to 6.x, which needs a separate effort to migrate my test cases to 6.x. Is there any work around with 5.x